# F12 (render image) keeps repeating

Tags: rendering

After I press F12, Blender (as expected) renders the current frame. But as soon as it has finished, it discards the product (without any opportunity for me to save it) and starts all over again, and again, and again ...

What's going on?

Comment: Sorry, no, 2.81. I have delete blender-render

Comment: I have not installed any other add-ons than those that came with Blender 2.81

Answer (score 1):

I inadvertently created 2 view layers. So it was not "again, and again", but only 2 repeats. I have deleted the layers, which solved the problem.

Comment: Congrats on solving this by yourself :). Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted later, so others can easily find it.